# What's the easiest way to update a JSON file in Java preserving the exact format

Tags: java, json

What's the easiest way to update a value in a JSON file, in Java, while preserving the original format. The JSON is large, nested, and has various kinds of JSON types.

From what I gathered, Java JSON libraries offer ways to "pretty print" but this overrides the original format.

Thanks in advance for any pointers!

Comment: You are aware of the fact that the format does not matter? I highly doubt there is a lib preserving the format because that is really complex and absolute unnecessary.

Comment: Treat it as text then..... happy parsing! But you won't have any of the benefits that JSON was meant for.

Comment: There are valid use cases for updating a json file while preserving formatting (or any other whitespace-agnostic format, for that matter). Humans read JSON, too.

Answer (score 0):

## Whitespace is irrelevant in JSON

If you are depending on the [white-space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_character) in a [JSON](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) file being arranged a certain way, you are doing something wrong. By definition, white space does not matter in JSON.

So the proper way to update a JSON file is to simply re-write it. Use any library that meets the rules of JSON, or write it yourself.

To quote [RFC 8259](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8259) section 2. *JSON Grammar*:

> Insignificant whitespace is allowed before or after any of the six structural characters.

## Consider XML

Note that JSON rules are quite loose and minimal. If you want strict detailed rules with robust enforcement by tooling, use [XML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML) and [Schema](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_schema) instead.

Indeed, you may want to consider switching to XML given that your JSON is “large, nested”. JSON was intended to be used for relatively small and flat data. But in XML too, whitespace is irrelevant.

## Data types

> various kinds of JSON types

JSON has only about [six data types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON#Data_types,_syntax_and_example): Number, String, Boolean, Array, Object, and null. Anything else is defined by your app, and such values should carry over as-is when re-writing another JSON file.

Again, if you want strict handling and enforcement of your custom data types, use XML & Schema instead. Don’t use a [mallet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mallet) when the job calls for a [sledgehammer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sledgehammer).